# Given a power series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the power series $\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{n=2} \frac{(-2)^n}{n(n-1)}x^n$

Let $ f(x) $ describe the sum function of the series on $ (-r,r) $.

Argue that $f$ is two times differentiable and show that $f''(x)=\displaystyle\frac{4}{1+2x} $

Comment: What are your ideas? What do you know about the termwise differentiability of power series? What is the radius of convergence $r$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is evident that given
\begin{align}
f(x) = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-2)^{n} \ x^{n}}{n(n-1)}
\end{align}
that
\begin{align}
f^{'}(x) &= \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-2)^{n} \ x^{n-1}}{n-1} \\
&= 2 \ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1} (2x)^{n}}{n} = 2 \ln(1+2x)
\end{align}
and 
\begin{align}
f^{''}(x) &= \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (-2)^{n} \ x^{n-2} \\
&= 4 \ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-2x)^{n} \\
&= \frac{4}{1+2x}. 
\end{align}
This is valid in $|x| < r$ except $x = -1/2$.